# Kafka producers log files/mySQL?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

I want to execute SQL on mySQL to get data every 10 minutes. Then I'd like to construct messages for each row and publish to kafka topics. Is this something I could/should do with Kafka? I want to open a mySQL connection in my Kafka Producer. The consumers (potentially across the WAN ) will get the messages (or rows) out and do whatever with the data.